# Add half a hunger point?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How would I add half a hunger point to a player when they are in a certain area?

I have got the detection part right I just don't know how to add exactly half a hunger point. Here is what I have tried so far:
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ grass 0 effect @p 23
but I know this is not the best way to do such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

To add half a hunger point, give the player a level 0 saturation for 1 second.

```
/effect @p minecraft:saturation 1 0
```

The levels are offset by 1 so that giving a level 0 effect with /effect actually gives the player a level 1 effect.

Comment: Edited: The effect level given by /effect behaves similarly to an array index where the first element (or effect level) is 0, not 1.